# How can I translate dynamic values from .Ts file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate, ngx-translate

I want to translate code sharing from one .ts file to another .ts file to be displayed by html file of latter.
**.t s file**

```
 constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
    private sharedService: SharedService,
   
    private service: RoleDashboardService,
  
    private router: Router) {
   
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    this.sharedService.language.subscribe(
      (language: string) => {
        this.translate.use(language);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.service.setBreadCrumbValue('Ticket');
   
  }
```

example :I want to translate Ticket , I am sendins this  on page load to another component through common service

Comment: did you try `translate.instant('Ticket')`, full code and same question is [here (github)](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/835)

Comment: yes I did, but its showing same result